# How to retrieve which layered navigation filters are applied in product list page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, layered-navigation, product-list, magento-2.1

I'm going to write a block to put in products list page. My question is how can I get to know which layered navigation filters are currently applied in the current list page ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any helps ?????

Comment: Hi michel Gokan did u implement this concept in magento 2 api level?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Did you try Giel's solution below? I asked this question about 2 years ago and I'm not working with Magento anymore but his solution works like a charm on that time. However, Magento evolved too much and I was working with 2.1 version.

Comment: thanks for your comments @michel, may i know whether the below concept will work for an API level? do u have any idea thanks

Comment: Please find the below link , i need to implement an api for magento 2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217261/magento2-layered-navigation-filters-applied-api

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the layer resolver (`Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver`). Example code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
)
{
    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $layer = $this->layerResolver->get();
    $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
}
```

**Edit**:

A small sidenote to those who might concern: you can only get the state after `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View::execute()` has already created the state. Otherwise you get a `Catalog Layer has been already created` runtime exception.

Comment: is it possible to implement the same at API Level? can u please suggest me thanks

Comment: Can you please suggest, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217261/magento2-layered-navigation-filters-applied-api